# Traceback Error in Python upon Second Run of code

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, traceback

I'm currently writing a Triangle Calculator, which solves a triangle according to the user's inputs, and draws the triangle using Turtle.
However, while it functions correctly for the first triangle, I am running into an error, when the code repeats itself and asks the user if he would like to draw another triangle.

This is the code that I have so far :

```
import math
import turtle


def ImpossibleTriangle():
    print ""
    print("That Triangle is imposssible, please try again: ")
    print ""
    return SSS()

def AngleLarge():
    AngleSize = int(input("That angle is too large, Try again: "))
    return AngleSize

def AngleZero():
    AngleSize = int(input("The angle cannot be zero, Try again: "))
    return AngleSize

def SideZero():
    ZeroLength = int(input("The length cannot be zero, Try again: "))
    return ZeroLength

def Sine(side, angleA, angleC):
    ExtraSide = abs(side*(math.sin(math.degrees(angleA)))/math.sin(math.degrees(angleC)))
    return ExtraSide # 'abs' used incase inputted values are negative

# Triangle given two angles and a side not between them

def AAS():
    print ""
    angleA = int(input("Please enter your first angle: "))

    while angleA>178:           # Angle cannot be greater than 178 because this
        angleA = AngleLarge()   # means that the other angles are not int but are floats
    while angleA == 0:
        angleA = AngleZero()
    else:
        angleC = int(input("Please enter your second angle: "))
        while (angleA+angleC)>179: # Again if it is >179 angleB will be a float
            angleC = AngleLarge()
        while angleC == 0:
            angleC = AngleZero()
    angleB = (180-(angleA + angleC)) # Calculates remaining angle
    sidec = int(input("Please enter the known side: "))
    sidea = Sine(sidec, angleA, angleC)
    sideb = Sine(sidec, angleB, angleC)

    sketch(sidea, sideb, sidec, angleA, angleB, angleC)

# Triangle with two angles and a side between them

def ASA():
    print ""
    angleA = int(input("Please enter you first angle: "))
    while angleA>=178:
        angleA = AngleLarge()
    while angleA == 0:
        angleA = AngleZero()
    angleB = int(input("Please enter your second angle: "))
    while (angleA + angleB) > 178:
        angleB = AngleLarge()
    while angleB == 0:
        angleB = AngleZero()
    angleC = (180-(angleA + angleB))

    sidec = int(input("Please enter the known side: "))
    while sidec == 0:
        sidec = SideZero()
    sidea = Sine(sidec, angleA, angleC)
    sideb = Sine(sidec, angleB, angleC)

    sketch(sidea, sideb, sidec, angleA, angleB, angleC)

# Triangle with only sides

def SSS():
    print ""
    sidea = int(input("Please enter your first side: "))
    while sidea == 0:
        sidea = SideZero()
    sideb = int(input("Please enter your second side: "))
    while sideb == 0:
        sideb = SideZero()
    sidec = int(input("Please enter your third side: "))
    while sidec == 0:
        sidec = SideZero()

    while sidea + sideb <= sidec or sideb + sidec <= sidea or sidea + sidec <= sideb:
        sidea, sideb, sidec = ImpossibleTriangle()

    angleA = int(math.degrees(math.acos(float(((sideb*sideb)+(sidec*sidec)-(sidea*sidea)))/float((2*sideb*sidec)))))
    angleB = int(math.degrees(math.acos(float(((sidec*sidec)+(sidea*sidea)-(sideb*sideb)))/float((2*sidec*sidea)))))
    angleC = (180-(angleA + angleB))

    sketch(sidea, sideb, sidec, angleA, angleB, angleC)

# Stating all values calculated, telling the user all information: 

def sketch(sidea, sideb, sidec, angleA, angleB, angleC):
    sidea = round(sidea,1)      # These lines round the decimal place
    sideb = round(sideb,1)      # of each of the known values to 'x'.
    sidec = round(sidec,1)      # If the values were not rounded then
    print ""
    print("These are the sides of your Triangle: - a, b, c -")
    print(sidea, sideb, sidec)


    angleA = round(angleA,1)    # it would result in the code printing 
    angleB = round(angleB,1)    # a longer string that we desire 
    angleC = round(angleC,1)    # it can be altered by changing the value. "1"
    print ""
    print("These are the angles of your Triangle: - A, B, C -")
    print(angleA, angleB, angleC)

# Drawing each line (direction and distance)

    TD = turtle.Turtle() # TD = Triangle Drawing

    TD.speed(1)          # This isn't important, though it can be used later
                         # in the GUI if desired...
    TD.forward(sidea)
    TD.left(180-angleC)
    TD.forward(sideb)
    TD.left(180-angleA)    
    TD.goto(0,0)

    turtle.Screen().exitonclick()

    return home2()

# Home Page

def Terminate():
    Quit = raw_input("Are you sure you want to quit? ")
    if Quit == "Yes" or Quit == "yes" or Quit == "y" or Quit == "Y":
        print ("Thankyou, Goodbye")
        exit()
    elif Quit == "No" or Quit == "no" or Quit == "n" or Quit == "N":
        print("Okay Great!")
        return TriangleFunc()

def TriangleFunc():
    print ""
    print ("Press Q to quit: ")
    Triangle = raw_input("How would you like to draw the triangle? - ASA, AAS, SSS - ")
    if Triangle == "ASA" or Triangle == "asa":
        ASA()
    elif Triangle == "AAS" or Triangle == "aas":
        AAS()
    elif Triangle == "SSS" or Triangle == "sss":
        SSS()
    elif Triangle == "Q" or Triangle == "q" or Triangle == "Quit" or Triangle == "quit":
        Terminate() # Convert this to a list?
    else:
        print("That value isn't valid - Please try again: ")
        TriangleFunc()

def home():
    Answer = raw_input("Would you like to draw a triangle? - (Yes/No) - ")
    if Answer == "Yes" or Answer == "yes" or Answer == "Y" or Answer == "y":
        TriangleFunc()        
    else:
        End = raw_input("Are you sure you want to quit? ")
        if End == "Yes" or End == "yes" or End =="Y" or End == "y":
            print ("Thankyou, Goodbye")
            exit()
        elif End == "No" or End == "no" or End =="N" or End == "n":
            return home()

def home2():
    print ""
    print("------AGAIN?-------")
    User = raw_input("Would you like to draw another Triangle? ")
    if User == "Yes" or User == "yes" or User == "Y" or User == "y":
        TriangleFunc()
    elif User == "No" or User == "no" or User =="N" or User == "n":
        Terminate()

home()
```

This is the error that I am receiving, when the user finishes inputting the values of the second triangle :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 179, in <module>
    home()
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 161, in home
    TriangleFunc()
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 147, in TriangleFunc
    ASA()
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 72, in ASA
    sketch(sidea, sideb, sidec, angleA, angleB, angleC)
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 129, in sketch
    return home2()
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 175, in home2
    TriangleFunc()
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 149, in TriangleFunc
    AAS()
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 48, in AAS
    sketch(sidea, sideb, sidec, angleA, angleB, angleC)
  File "C:\Users\Path to program.py", line 117, in sketch
    TD = turtle.Turtle() # TD = Triangle Drawing
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 3707, in __init__
    visible=visible)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 2462, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 2565, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 2551, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\turtle.py", line 1240, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
Terminator
```

I apologize for dumping this block of code without any potential solutions, but I really don't have an idea as to what could be the issue.
Thank you in advance,
Noahf99

Comment: What values are using for the second triangle? Please give input examples too. Also, in `ImpossibleTriangle()` I think you mean to call `SSS()` rather than returning it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your call to `turtle.Screen().exitonclick()` in `sketch()`.  Once you call this method, you turn control over to tkinter and you can't get it back.  Move this call to the very end of your file, after your call to `home()`.  Or leave it out altogether if you want your window to close after the user's second confirmation that they want to quit.

This problem has nothing to do with *singletons* so I'd ignore that advice.

Comment: Right, I deleted the answer.